# Android available memory in device at the time of downloading?

Tags: android

How to check the available memory in android when user is downloading the media into the sdCard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following to check the memory status:

```
ActivityManager actMgr = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
ActivityManager.MemoryInfo minfo = new ActivityManager.MemoryInfo();
actMgr.getMemoryInfo(minfo);
long mem = minfo.availMem;
```